# Sitecore TreelistEx search with Lucene.NET

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, contains

Is there a way to search contents of a TreeListEx field in a custom index inside Sitecore with Lucene.NET? I have tried to use a WildQuery to figure out if an item is part of the TreeListEx field but it's not working. Below is a code sample of what I tried -

```
WildcardQuery taggingQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term("country tag", ShortID.Encode("{4ED2F7EE-5C2A-418C-B2F6-236F94166BA1}").ToLowerInvariant()));
```

I am basically trying to do a "contains" and WildCardQuery is the only way I could figure of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've paid more attention when setting up the index. I forgot to add field analyzers for each field. The multilist fields were getting indexed with a different analyzer instead of the standard analyzer. I added this to my config section for field crawls and my query started working

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldTypes">
                  <!-- Text fields need to be tokenized -->
                  <fieldType name="single-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="multi-line text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="word document" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="html" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="rich text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="memo" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="text" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Multilist based fields need to be tokenized to support search of multiple values -->
                  <fieldType name="multilist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="treelistex" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <fieldType name="checklist" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                  <!-- Legacy tree list field from ver. 5.3 -->
                  <fieldType name="tree list" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" />
                </fieldTypes>
```